# How to add 10k concurrent users on a website using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, load, performance-testing, stress

The requirement is to start with 500 users initially and then increase slowly till 10 thousand.

I am new to performance testing, it would be great if anyone could guide me with the steps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to go for [Stepping Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/) where you can specify how many threads to start initially and how to increase the load gradually.

Example setup

[image]

Stepping Thread Group can be installed using **Custom Thread Groups** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)